# What happens if you add a constant value to all input data points to neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, feature-engineering, feature-scaling

I have a somewhat basic question about neural networks. What would be the effect on the performance of a neural network if we add a constant value to all data points? For example, suppose you have temperature data in degree Celcius which is not an SI unit. Will it make any difference to the model if your input is in degree Celcius or Kelvin? If yes, then in what way?

I have a dataset where one feature values are in nanometers for example `35nm`, `42nm`, etc. If the answer to the above question is No then you can simply divide all of them by 100 to reduce them between `0` and `1` and it shouldn't matter to the model? Does it make more sense to divide it by `100` or the maximum value? What do you do if your input is limited by neither `100` nor the maximum value?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a linear transformation, so that it is okay to do that. However, NN usually work best with „small numbers“. This is why input features are usually scaled, so that they have mean=0 and SD=1.

Comment: Yeah, I can scale them but the thing that's bugging me is that those scaling will be done relative to maximum and minimum values but the data is not bounded by them in real.

Comment: You mean because of making predictions? Should be no problem if you also scale the data to be predicted by the same way as you scaled the train data. Maybe this helps (section preparing data) https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/3.7-predicting-house-prices.ipynb